# URISyntaxException - How to deal with urls with %

Tags: url, http-get

I am fairly new to Java and came across this issue. I tried searching but never got a correct answer.

I have a string for example

```
String name = anything 10%-20% 04-03-07
```

Now I need to build up a url string with this String name like below.

```
http://something.com/test/anything 10%-20% 04-03-07
```

I tried replacing the spaces with %20 and now I am getting the new url as

```
http://something.com/test/anything%2010%-20%%2004-03-07
```

When I use this url and fire it in firefox it just works fine but while processing in Java it is apparently throwing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.net.URI.create(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:69)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Malformed escape pair at index 39 : 
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.scanEscape(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.scan(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
... 6 more
```

This is the code throwing error

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Encode also the percent sign with `%25`.

`http://something.com/test/anything 10%-20% 04-03-07` would work with `http://something.com/test/anything%2010%25-20%25%2004-03-07`.

You should be able to use for example [URLEncoder.encode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for this - just remember, that you need to urlencode the path part, not anything before that, so something like

```
String encodedUrl =
    String.format("http://something.com/%s/%s",
      URLEncoder.encode("test", "UTF-8"),
      URLEncoder.encode("anything 10%-20% 04-03-07", "UTF-8")
    );
```

Note: URLEncoder encodes spaces to `+` instead of `%20`, but it should work equally well, both are ok.

Comment: Thanks That works perfectly. I was trying to escape it off. Didnt think from a replacement perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [java.net.URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) to create a uri from your string

```
String url = "http://something.com/test/anything 10%-20% 04-03-07"

URI uri = new URI(
    url,
    null);
String request = uri.toASCIIString();

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(request);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```