# Malformed escape pair at index 103: http://localhost:8025/oauth2db/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=nithi5@gmail.com&password=nithi%"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to do oAuth2 DB authentication, 
below is the code snippet which I am using having tokenUrl as 
 `http://localhost:8025/oauth2db/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=nithi5@gmail.com&password=nithi%`

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(tokenUrl);
        try {
                String auth = authConfiguration.getDatabaseClientId() + ":" + authConfiguration.getDatabaseClientSecret();
                byte[] authEncrypted = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));
                httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(authEncrypted));
            }

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

On doing this Im getting error as

```
"Malformed escape pair at index 103: http://localhost:8025/oauth2db/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=nithi5@gmail.com&password=nithi%"
```

Below I am attaching complete log

```
2018-02-14 11:28:08.991  INFO 18028 --- [nio-8027-exec-1] c.a.s.c.oauth2.OAuth2Controller          :  *********Login WithDataBase***************** 
2018-02-14 11:28:08.991  INFO 18028 --- [nio-8027-exec-1] com.altimetrik.security.util.OAuth2Util  : token URLhttp://localhost:8025/oauth2db/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=nithi5@gmail.com&password=nithi%
2018-02-14 11:28:09.004 ERROR 18028 --- [nio-8027-exec-1] c.a.s.exception.RESTExceptionHandler     : Error occured in App. Error Message is  : Malformed escape pair at index 103: http://localhost:8025/oauth2db/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=nithi5@gmail.com&password=nithi%

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed escape pair at index 103: http://localhost:8025/oauth2db/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=nithi5@gmail.com&password=nithi%
    at java.net.URI.create(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:73) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at com.altimetrik.security.util.OAuth2Util.getTokenVO(OAuth2Util.java:93) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.altimetrik.security.controller.oauth2.OAuth2Controller.loginWithDatabase(OAuth2Controller.java:73) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Malformed escape pair at index 103: http://localhost:8025/oauth2db/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=nithi5@gmail.com&password=nithi%
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.scanEscape(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.scan(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    ... 58 common frames omitted

2018-02-14 11:28:09.006  WARN 18028 --- [nio-8027-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed escape pair at index 103: http://localhost:8025/oauth2db/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=nithi5@gmail.com&password=nithi%
```

Comment: I believe % at end is causing the problem, try puttting it inside quotes 'nithi%''

Comment: @akshaya pandey even putting it inside quotes 'nithi%' giving same error. Facing same error with both % and ^

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422256/urisyntaxexception-how-to-deal-with-urls-with

Answer (score 6):

URL query parameters must be URL-encoded so they don't contain special characters. For example `&` in a parameter value would be considered as a start of a new parameter. The `%` character is used to introduce an escape sequence (e.g. %20 is a space character), so it cannot be used alone and the parser complains about it:

```
Malformed escape pair
```

The solution is to URL encode all your parameter values. Probably the easiest way is to use Spring's own [`UriComponentsBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html):

```
String url = UriComponentsBuilder
    .fromHttpUrl('http://localhost:8025/oauth2db/oauth/token')
    .queryParam('password', 'nithi%')
    ... // all other parameters here
    .build()
    .encode() // This will URL-encode the parameter values
    .toUriString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encoded the username and password before doing `httpClient.execute(httpPost);` and it works fine for me.

below is my code snippet:

```
public String getTokenURL(String username, String password) {
        StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        urlBuilder.append(authConfiguration.getDatabaseServiceUrl());
        urlBuilder.append("/");
        urlBuilder.append(authConfiguration.getDatabaseServiceContextPath());
        urlBuilder.append("/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=");
        try {
            urlBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8"));
            urlBuilder.append("&password=");
            urlBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return urlBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AsyncTaskRunnerCredit extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        try {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://sleepy-dusk-58079.herokuapp.com/generateToken?website=DEFAULT&orderId=430037&amount=1.00&callbackUrl=https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=4779&custId=4779&mode=0&mid=ThePha92698482954160&key_secret=MMhZHQULZunoL%23x%")
                    .method("GET", null)
                    .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            String s = response.toString();
            String m = response.body().string();
            String b = response.message();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exc1 ", e.getMessage());
        }


        return null;

    }

}
```

Comment: implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'                  //library